# Block Root REST API Route using custom &/or iThemes

Tags: plugins, rest-api, security

I'm looking to block the following REST API Routes **/wp-json/** & **/wp-json/v2/users/**

I have iThemes currently installed that handles the users route, but would prefer to block the root route also.

Looking for a simple solution to either add in the functions.php file without conflicting with the iThemes security plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all REST API routes, the [rest_api_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/) action hook fires when preparing to serve a REST API request. The request URI ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) can be inspected with a regular expression to detect the root (e.g. wp-json) and the route (e.g. /wp/v2/posts) of the request. You can then decide what to return to the client (e.g. WP_Error, friendly message, [Link Relation Names](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/#links) with alternative routes, etc).

## Update

Found the code snippet below [here](https://wpdynamic.com/wordpress-developer/wordpress-code-snippets/how-to-disable-the-wordpress-json-rest-api-without-plugin/). You could try adding a conditional statement with Regex on the Request_URI inside the [rest_authentication_errors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_authentication_errors/) callback to see if it is effective for filtering requests.

```
<?php
    add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'wp_snippet_disable_rest_api' );
    function wp_snippet_disable_rest_api( $access ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_disabled', __('The WordPress REST API has been disabled.'), array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code()));
    }
?>
```

Comment: I was trying to get this code to return for the URI /wp-json/
However, it seems that iThemes is taking priority over my function. Any idea how this could be returned prior to iThemes response?


`add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'rest_api_block_root',0);
function rest_api_block_root() {

    $route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($route == '/wp-json/' || $route == '/wp-json/users/') {        
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_route_blocked', 'No access given for the matching the URL and request method.', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
    }

}`

Comment: Would you know if the iThemes plugin provides [pluggable functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) or action and filter hooks that allow you to [override](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php) their behaviours?

Comment: @WilsonP It's better to [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415674/edit) to include your code snippet. It'll be easier to read and it'll keep all the parts of your question together.